# Javafx Stage.setFullScreen() auto minimizes when clicking another application

Tags: java, javafx

**Context**: In a multi-monitor setup, I start a JavaFx application in Full Screen mode in 1 of the screens. Different applications are open in other screens.

**Issue**: Once the JavaFx application starts, the moment I click on another application in another screen, the JavaFx app full screen minimizes to the application bar.

**Research**: I refer to inputs in [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49223820/3127144) [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35673607/javafx-changing-scenes-on-fullscreen-mode) [Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34812692/javafx-fullscreen-application-gets-minimized-when-alert-message-is-shown) but in those cases they are trying to change scenes within the same full-screen application. In this case I am clicking on an unrelated application in another screen yet the full screen app minimizes.

Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

**Main:**

```
 @Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
    primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public class Controller {}
```

**FXML:**

```
<GridPane fx:controller="sample.Controller"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10"></GridPane>
```

Comment: Did you play around? `Stage.setFullScreenExitKeyCombination(KeyCombination.NO_MATCH);` / overriding `toBack() {}`?

Comment: @JoopEggen yes I did try that as well as mentioned in those links, but doesnt work. Unable to figure out why clicking another unrelated application is changing behavior of this application

Comment: Yeah, front-to-back or focus-lost might have done that. Of course there is the source code, for a break point.

Comment: I Just tested this on my multi monitor Mac ide intellij java 8 this doesn't happen to me what are your specs is your application in a .jar or ide idk if this makes a difference?

Comment: @Matt I am using windows 10, JDK10 Intellij ide, its still in dev stage so no jar of the application yet.

Comment: An update, I notice that the fullscreen app does not minimize remains in fullscreen mode but just goes to background when I click on another application in any other screen. I guess it is more of Windows OS thing & not something that can be controlled from within FX. Hope an expert confirms this or points at what I need to do to achieve it.